# Manipular archivo .asc con PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, csv

Quiero subir un archivo `.asc` e insertarlo a mi base datos MySQL.

El contenido del archivo es similar a esto:

> 3884|5000007|160|1|IN|160||HME980330SL3|MESJ540212HDFRNR02|14.71800|0|0|0|0|0|8827.700|7|1|1|9|spartan
>   K|CARRT. PANAMERICANA K.M. 5.5|2-A -
>   L-C|SN|36100|SILAO|GT|MEX|1|2015-01-06 16:43:49|2015-01-06 16:54:50|

La idea es la siguiente:

1. Programar el botón "seleccionar archivo"
2. seleccionar el archivo
3. Subirlo y cargarlo en mi BD

¿Alguna idea de cómo hacerlo? este es mi controlador csv.php
el archivo es separado por pipes trate de manipularlo como .csv pero no se como cambiar las "," por pipes.

```
<?php

class Csv extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('csv_model');
        $this->load->library('csvreader');
        $this->load->library('csvimport');
    }

    function index() {
        $data['addressbook'] = $this->csv_model->get_addressbook();
        $this->load->view('csvindex', $data);
    }

    function importcsv() {
        $data['addressbook'] = $this->csv_model->get_addressbook();
        $data['error'] = '';    //initialize image upload error array to empty

        $config['upload_path'] = './static/uploads';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
        $config['max_size'] = '1000';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);


        // If upload failed, display error
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
            $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();

            $this->load->view('csvindex', $data);
        } else {
            $file_data = $this->upload->data();
            $file_path =  './static/uploads/'.$file_data['file_name'];

            if ($this->csvimport->get_array($file_path)) {
                $csv_array = $this->csvimport->get_array($file_path);
                foreach ($csv_array as $row) {
                    $insert_data = array(
                        'firstname'=>$row['firstname'],
                        'lastname'=>$row['lastname'],
                        'phone'=>$row['phone'],
                        'email'=>$row['email'],
                    );
                    $this->csv_model->insert_csv($insert_data);
                }
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Tu archivo a sido subido exitosamente');
                redirect(base_url().'csv');
                echo "<pre>"; print_r($insert_data);
            } else 
                $data['error'] = "Error occured";
                $this->load->view('csvindex', $data);
            }     
        }      
}
```

Comment: Hola @Rickzize. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te comento que tu pregunta puede ser interpretada como demasiado amplia porque no estás mostrando qué intentaste y estás pidiendo que te resuelvan todo... ¿Podrías mostrar tu código, por más que tenga partes que no funcionan? Y ¿qué de todo lo que estás preguntando te está trayendo problemas? ¿El formulario, el envío, o grabarlo en la base de datos?

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es insertar cada valor separado por "pipe" en un campo de una tabla de la Base de Datos, podrías probar lo siguiente:

```
$contenido = file_get_contents(path/to/file/uploaded);

if ( $contenido != "" )
{
     $lineas = explode("\n", $contenido);

     if ( count($linias) > 0 )
     {
         foreach ( $lineas AS $linea )
         {
             if ( $linea != "" )
             {  
                 $campos = explode("|", $linea);
                 if ( count($campos) > 0 )
                 {
                     foreach ( $campos AS $campo )
                     {  
                        $data = [
                           'campo1' => $campo[.....],
                            ......,
                            'campoN' => $campo[.....],  
                        ];

                        // Dando por hecho que tienes un modelo y un 
                        // método en él para ejecutar los inserts en la DB
                        $this->model->insertar($row);
                      }
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
 ......... validación de los inserts, etc
```

Espero que te resulte útil.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer estás utilizando CodeIgniter, por lo que revisé el código de la clase `Csvimport` en [GitHub](https://github.com/bradstinson/csv-import/blob/master/libraries/csvimport.php).  La manera de indicar el delimitador es utilizando el parámetro `$delimiter` en la llamada del método `get_array`:

```
$this->csvimport->get_array($file_path, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, '|')
```